# How to convert dd/mm/yyyy string into JavaScript Date object using date-fns?

Tags: javascript, date-fns

I am converting `dd/mm/yyyy` string into JavaScript `Date` object. My code is working but is there any better way to do it by using `date-fns`? My current solution is:

```
calculateDate(value: string>): Date {
    const dateParts = value?.split('/');
    const calcualtedDate = value && new Date(dateParts[2] + '/' + dateParts[1] + '/' + dateParts[0]);
    return calcualtedDate;
  }
```

I  tried **date-fns** parse but it return Invalid date.

Comment: Do you mean _"can `date-fns` parse a string"_? Then: yes. Did you read [the docs](https://date-fns.org/docs/Getting-Started)?

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes, I tried is but it returns Invalid date

Comment: Are you asking if there's a better way to do it in general, or specifically *how* to do it using `data-fns`?

Comment: @freedomn-m I am asking about data-fns but also if there is other option for doing it better than current solution

Comment: I have edited my question but still it is closed. Please help me to reopen it

Comment: Tried _what_, exactly? Give a [mre].

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [docs](https://date-fns.org/docs/Getting-Started), most notably the docs on [parse](https://date-fns.org/v2.30.0/docs/parse), and look at the table which describes the formatting string.

If you're using the format string that you use in your question (`dd/mm/yyyy`) you'll notice that `mm (lowercase)` represents minutes, like `00, 01, ..., 59` and `MM (capitalized)` represents months like `01, 02, ..., 12`.

Parsing with the correct format string works, see snippet below:

```js
console.log(parse('24/10/2023', 'dd/MM/yyyy', new Date()));
```

```html
<script type="module">
  import { parse } from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/date-fns@2.30.0/+esm'
  
  window.parse = parse;
</script>
```